# Who was Lister's Grandmother?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-dwarf

In [Red Dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf) S01E02- [Future Echoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Echoes), when Lister is showing some of his photographs to Cat,

> **Cat**: Who's that guy?
>   **Lister**: That's me grandmother

[image: Lister's grandmother]

However, in S07E03- [Ouroboros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros_%28Red_Dwarf%29), it's revealed that

> Lister is his own father, and his mother is [Kochanski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kristine_Kochanski), and he went back in time to abandon himself as a baby so that humanity will always exist.

With this in mind, is there any explanation as to who his Grandmother is or could be?

Comment: The first two seasons have been mostly retconned. Not that internal consistency was ever a Red Dwarf thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I agree that Red Dwarf is loose with its own history, and I wouldn't think too hard about inconsistencies from (in particular) the first 2 seasons.
However,
Lister was adopted, and so I've always thought the woman pictured was one of his adopted parents mothers. It's frequently mentioned throughout the show (often by Rimmer as a putdown) that he was adopted.

But as I said, Red Dwarf isn't one for letting its own history spoil a potentially good gag.

Answer (score -1):

All we really know about his grandmother is that she was a grand old lady; she nutted the teacher once because Lister got expelled from school for coming bottom of the class in French.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked in any meaningful way